# Matching regex patterns in order

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building a mini parser which will take images or attachments and build an array of the data for my own use later.

I can successfully parse my data with my patterns, however, the way that I am parsing the original text is by running two separate match loops to get the data and push into an array.

As a result, the order of the data in my final array is out of order relative to the original text.   Here is an example:

**Original Data**

```
[ATTACH]1234[/ATTACH]
[IMG]http://www.google.com/abc.gif[/IMG]
[ATTACH]5678[/ATTACH]
[IMG]http://www.google.com/def.gif[/IMG]
```

**RESULT ARRAY**

```
0 : http://www.google.com/abc.gif
1 : http://www.google.com/def.gif
2 : 1234
3 : 5678
```

In actuality, I would want the result array to look like this

**DESIRED RESULT ARRAY**

```
0 : 1234
1 : http://www.google.com/abc.gif
2 : 5678
3 : http://www.google.com/def.gif
```

Here is a shortened version of the code I am using the do this

```
//Container Array of Images
var imagesContainerArray = {};
var daC = 0;
var finalData = {};


//Individual Images 
var pattern = /\[IMG]([\s\S]*?)\[\/IMG\]/gi;
var match;

while (match = pattern.exec(text)) {  

    finalImageUrl = match[1];

            //Other stuff i'm doing 

    imagesContainerArray[daC] = finalImageUrl;

    daC++;
}

//Individual ATTACH 
var pattern = /\[ATTACH]([\s\S]*?)\[\/ATTACH\]/gi;
var match;

while (match = pattern.exec(text)) {  

    finalImageUrl = match[1];

            //Other stuff i'm doing 

    imagesContainerArray[daC] = finalImageUrl;

    daC++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all in one pattern:

```
var pattern = /\[(IMG|ATTACH)]([\s\S]*?)\[\/\1\]/gi;
var match;

while (match = pattern.exec(text)) {  

    finalImageUrl = match[2];

    imagesContainerArray[daC] = finalImageUrl;

    daC++;
}
```

To apply different treatment according to the tag name, you can use a switch/case statement. Example:

```
var pattern = /\[(IMG|ATTACH)]([\s\S]*?)\[\/\1\]/gi;
var match;

while (match = pattern.exec(text)) {  

    finalImageUrl = match[2];

    switch (match[1].toUpperCase()) {
        case "IMG":    ...
                       break;
        case "ATTACH": ...
                       break;
        ...
    }

    imagesContainerArray[daC] = finalImageUrl;

    daC++;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, however the problem is that I have a few other processes that need to be performed depending on if we are matching IMG or ATTACH

Comment: @Mark: it's not a problem since you can refer to the tag name with `match[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If the inputs are always in pairs like that you can insert them into your "array" (noting that what you are calling an "array" is actually not, it's a plain "object") like this:

```
//Individual Images 
var pattern = /\[IMG]([\s\S]*?)\[\/IMG\]/gi;
var match;
daC = 1;  // <=- Note starting index
while (match = pattern.exec(text)) {
    finalImageUrl = match[1];
            //Other stuff i'm doing 
    imagesContainerArray[daC] = finalImageUrl;
    daC+=2;
}
//Individual ATTACH 
var pattern = /\[ATTACH]([\s\S]*?)\[\/ATTACH\]/gi;
var match;
daC = 0;  // <=- Note starting index
while (match = pattern.exec(text)) {
    finalImageUrl = match[1];
            //Other stuff i'm doing 
    imagesContainerArray[daC] = finalImageUrl;
    daC+=2;
}
```

That is, insert the "ATTACH" items with even-numbered indexes, and insert the "IMG" items with odd-numbered indexes.

Comment: They wont actually always be in pairs like that, in fact it will be a long list of images and attachments, all in a very random order and distribution :(